# How to get Seek Scroll animation in Anime.js or Javascript? I have reference what I want to do

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, scroll, anime.js

Here is the animation by using bar: http://animejs.com/documentation/#seekAnim but I want to do it in scroll event.

Here is another reference for scroll seek animation : https://webflow.com/

Comment: Do you have an example of what you've tried already?

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to do it or how should I start :(